How to properly use an enameled cast iron grill pan?
I was given an enameled cast iron grilling pan. As I'm entirely inexperienced with cooking using either enameled cast iron or grilling pans, this is way out of my league. I am failing to use it for something as simple as grilling a sausage. I've tried a few times so far, and each time the result is the same: The sausage skin sticks to the pan, rips away from the sausage when trying to turn it, and the entire pan gets filled with a big black/brown burnt mess that requires loads of soaking and cleaning afterwards, no matter if I use some oil or none at all. My best attempt still looks like this
The instructions that came with the pan were pretty clear: Before first use, rinse with warm water and let air-dry. Then wipe some oil over the surface of the pan. Because I'm cooking on an induction plate, I'm supposed to pre-heat the pan for 5 minutes on a third of it's full power (to avoid thermal shock), then I can turn the heat all the way up. Dropping in a small drop of water it starts sizzling and evaporating immediately, which according to the internet is a sign the pan has reached the right temperature. I could try using more oil, but the whole purpose of a grilling pan (the reason I asked for one) was that you don't need to use any extra oil or butter to grill at all.
What else can I try to be able to use this pan properly?

How soon are you trying to move the food?  meat will usually sticks, then loosen up as it cooks if the pan is oiled slightly and properly pre-heat and

@Joe I've tried "fast" and "wait until it starts to smell burnt" and some attempts in between, similar results all around just different shades of 'grill marks' and 'goo left in the pan'.

Usually I try pushing or lifting things slightly, and once they start to release, go ahead and flip them over.  If it doesn't want to move, I just wait a little longer.   Sometimes it takes a little bit of force, but it's MUCH less than what's needed a couple of minutes after you put it down


Dropping in a small drop of water it starts sizzling and evaporating immediately, which according to the internet is a sign the pan has reached the right temperature.

I see this online a lot too, but in my experience what you want is the Leidenfrost effect, that means the water will hang for a second or two before evaporating .
Some people recommend an infrared thermometer for further consistency, but I personally don't use one.
That being said, I also don't think you should ever heat it all the way up when you're cooking sausages, they necessitate less heat then say steak.
I agree with the comment you got by Joe, you might be trying to flip/move stuff too soon. The food should release naturally from the pan when it's properly seared.
Finally are you accounting for the temperature of the food you're putting in? letting it defrost properly and what not?

I haven't tried any previously frozen meat in this pan, just all fresh, so there was no need for defrosting. Does it need to be warmer than just 10-15 minutes on the counter outside the fridge would make it? I'm hesitant to let it get too warm for too long, as that'll mean it spoils.

No, that particular bit of advice is only for previously frozen stuff. fresh should be the perfect temperature.

So, any luck? I was thinking about this post today because I went to a friend's house and they had an infrared thermometer and I gotta say it's pretty handy, my friend had various temps written down for various foods for consistency sake. I think they're not very expensive.

sorry, no sausages yet. It might be a few weeks before I try again.

I agree that the temperature may be too high. I use a enamel grill pan to grill burgers, hot dogs, and chicken. You should expect some mess afterwards, but if you grill on medium high heat and not high heat, you shouldn't have the sausages stick to the pan. Always use a non-metal spatula and cleaning tool or your pan will peel and get ruined. Good luck!
